# Best way to initialize an Contextual Tab?

Tags: master-page, ribbon, postback

I've a custom contextual ribbon tab element and I'm initializing it throw the following code on a webcontrol hosted on the masterpage:

```
   protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
    {
        LoadRibbonCustomTab("MyRibbonTab", SPRibbon.GetCurrent(Page));
        base.OnPreRender(e);
    }

    public void LoadRibbonCustomTab(string tabId, SPRibbon ribbon)
    {
        if (ribbon == null) return;
        ribbon.Minimized = false;
        ribbon.CommandUIVisible = true;

        if (!ribbon.IsTabAvailable(tabId))
            ribbon.MakeTabAvailable(tabId);
    }
```

but every time I get a page load a weird thing just occur, the SPRibbon just shift down and get back to the original place. What I'm doing wrong? Any other optimized/cleanest way to initialize this? Any opinions r welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public void LoadRibbonCustomTab(string tabId, SPRibbon ribbon)
{
        if (ribbon == null) return;
        ribbon.Minimized = false;
        ribbon.CommandUIVisible = true;

        if (!ribbon.IsTabAvailable(tabId))
            ribbon.MakeTabAvailable(tabId);

        ribbon.InitialTabId = tabId;
}
```

Comment: actually, I have already tried like that, but it gets even worst. It gets MyRibbonTab selected, yes, but right bellow it the 'Browse' Tab also open. in other words, a mess! but thanks a lot for the reply